# $g : [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is a concave function with $g(0) =0$ and $g(1)= \beta$. Show that $g(z) \geq \beta z$, $z \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, functional-inequalities

I came across the following,
let $g : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be a concave function with $g(0) =0$ and $g(1)= \beta$. It implies $g(z) \geq \beta z$, $z \in [0,1]$.
Why is the statement $g(z) \geq \beta z$ true?

Comment: This is pretty obvious if you graph it.

Comment: @Goldname Perhaps posting the graph would be helpful, then.

Comment: @TheCount Oh no, not you again.

Comment: @Goldname I don't know what you mean, but if graphing provides an obvious solution, it sounds like it would be helpful to post.

Comment: @Goldname how do you post a "generic" concave function? A continuous one gives the intution for sure, but I'm curious how you would explain how to extrapolate to the general case.

Comment: @AdamHughes Like you said, the secant line is below the graph of every concave function. So if you draw that line, which can be considered "least" concave, it becomes obvious.

Comment: @Goldname right, I agree, but I'm looking for where that isn't circular:  the definitions are what imply the geometry, so I'm trying to see how you can get the "general shape" of a concave graph without already knowing it has this property and ending up using circular reasoning. i.e. "it's below the secant because I drew this graph where all the points are below the secant"

Comment: @AdamHughes This isn't circular reasoning. You want to draw a concave line, intuition says to consider the cases where the line approaches $\beta*z$ the most. That line is the the least concave line. It's not a rigorous proof but I'm sure you can extrapolate something out of it.

Comment: @Goldname how do you know what a concave graph looks like without the definitions though? Like, if I draw one squiggle and you draw another, how can we tell which (if any) are the thing we're calling "concave?" It doesn't seem you're advocating for using the graph as a proof, so I think what you might be trying to say is to use a graph of something you intuit as "concave" for motivation, in which case I agree, but I want to be sure since your original comment looks like "if you draw a picture, that's enough to answer the question," which it looks like you might not have intended to say.

Comment: @AdamHughes Why are you handicapping me from using the definition of concave? I never said you can draw a concave line while ignoring the definition of it. Also, I'm curious to know, are there rigorous proofs through visualization? I never heard of such things, but I definitely didn't mean that it was possible.

Comment: @Goldname the standard definition of concave is $f(x)$ is concave iff $-f(x)$ is convex, where convex means $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(x)$ with $0\le\lambda\le 1$. I'm not saying you shouldn't use it, I was trying to figure out if you were using a words description or the actual inequality as it was unclear from what you wrote, and it's impossible to tell since there are a plenty of users who use intuitive definitions rather than rigorous ones. In short:  I don't think you necessarily were talking in circles, but it wasn't clear from how you were explaining it.

Comment: @AdamHughes I wasn't aware of the formal definition, but I was aware of its existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secant line from $[0,1]$ is

> $$y-0= {\beta -0\over 1-0}(x-0)$$

By definition of concavity, the secant line is below the graph of the function on any interval, so the result immediately follows.

Answer (score 3):

By [definition of concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Definition) on interval $[0,1]$, for any $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]\,$:

$$
g\big((1 - \lambda) \cdot 0 + \lambda \cdot 1\big) \;\ge\; (1-\lambda) \cdot g(0) + \lambda\cdot g(1)
$$

Writing the above for $\lambda = z \in [0,1]\,$ with $\,g(0)=0\,$ and $\,g(1)=\beta\,$ gives $\,g(z) \ge z \cdot \beta\,$.